# What preposition should be used in “the award was conferred {to/on} him”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

There was this question where one has to fill in the blanks with correct preposition. The sentence was:

> "....the award was conferred ________ him.".

Naively I wrote "to" and moved ahead but my friend pointed out that the correct answer is "on". And now that I see it both sound equally correct to me. But still I'm not convinced which one is correct. And how do you generally figure out what's the correct preposition?

Comment: You can just replace your underscores by an asterisk and [create a Google NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=award+was+conferred+*+him&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) From which it's obvious that the only alternative to ***on*** here is the somewhat more starchy / dated form of "the same" preposition - ***upon***. Physical things are ***transferred to*** a recipient, but "abstract" titles / honours / attributes are ***conferred on*** him.

Comment: Native speakers learn such things by hearing other native speakers and by reading texts where they occur.

Comment: Better still, use a dictionary that contains usage examples, such as Cambridge Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

"Conferred" is used with "on." The reason it sounds ok to you is probably that there are many similar verbs that could use "to": given to him, awarded to him, presented to him.